# Internal Microphone not working with Ubuntu 13.10 on Compaq CQ-45

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, hda-intel

I am unable to get the internal microphone working with Ubuntu.
It works perfectly with Windows.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
01:05.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780 HDMI Audio [Radeon (HD) 3000 Series]
```

I am using a laptop Compaq CQ-45 with an AMD Turion X2 64 bit processor with Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit version.

Comment: To help other users, please add the model/make of your computer in the title (this seems a very specific thing). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I searched some solutions on the Internet. Following worked for me.

- I have added to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` the following lines and worked for me:

  ```
  options snd-pcsp index=-2    
  alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel    
  alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel    
  options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m4-1    
  options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=1    
  options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1 enable=yes
  ```
- And then in Pulse Audio volume control, I set the Built-in Audio to "Analog Stereo Input".